# Получение айди стикера pytelegrambotAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

как получить айди стикера который отправляет пользователь py telegram bot API?

Comment: А почему удалили предыдущий вопрос с стикером? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1203026

Comment: Я более правильно сформулировал вопрос

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка `править` ею можно редактировать вопрос ;)

Comment: спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["sticker"])
def send_sticker(message):
    # Получим ID Стикера
    sticker_id = message.sticker.file_id
```

Comment: а возможно ли как то получить emoji стикера?